# How to remove NULL from the output in R

Tags: r

I have tried this code to get expected output

```
condition<- function(temp){

V<- for (i in temp){
    if(i > 100){ cat ('"Hot" ')}
    else { cat ('"Normal" ')}


}
return(V)
}
print(condition(c(102,98,67,115)))
print(condition(c(89,125)))
print(condition(c(99,45,56)))
```

output - extra NULL added at the end

```
"Hot" "Normal" "Normal" "Hot" NULL 
"Normal" "Hot" NULL
"Normal" "Normal" "Normal" NULL
```

expected output -

```
[1] "Hot" "Normal" "Normal" "Hot"
[1] "Normal" "Hot"
[1] "Normal" "Normal" "Normal"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ifelse` -

```
condition<- function(temp){
  ifelse(temp > 100, 'Hot', 'Cold')
}

condition(c(102,98,67,115))
#[1] "Hot"  "Cold" "Cold" "Hot"
```

Answer (score 0):

We may do this without an `ifelse`

```
condition <- function(temp) {
     c("Cold", "Hot")[1 + (temp > 100)]
}
```

testing

```
condition(c(102, 98, 67, 115))
[1] "Hot"  "Cold" "Cold" "Hot"
```